# What is this Austrian pork dish called?

Tags: food-identification

[image]

> A traditional Austrian pork dish, served with potato croquettes, vegetables, mushrooms and gravy

From: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ9zA.jpg

Comment: Where is the picture and quote from?

Comment: @Cindy http://imgur.com/gallery/35BwvDi

Answer (score 1):

The original source of this image is from a photographer named KF, Gmunden, taken in Austria on July 2005.

Here is the original source on the internet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pork_.JPG

With a reverse Google Image search and more digging, this doesn't appear to be a named dish. Rather, the amalgamation of these ingredients is typical, as suggested by the original wiki upload. If the dish had a name, it would have been tagged when the file was uploaded to Wikipedia.

Comment: Isn't it strange to claim it "traditional" then, if it wasn't well-known as well?

Comment: I think what is traditional about the pictured dish is that it is common to include several or all of these components on a plate. Pork, potatoes, vegetables, gravy.